# How to display the date in different formats in the console?

Tags: c#, class, date, datetime

How to display the date in different formats in the console? I need to make a class that can output the date in different formats (dd/mm/yyyy, dd.mm.yyyy, dd.mmmm.yyyy)

```
 class FunctionWithDate
    {
    public int DifferentInDays(DateTime day1)
    {
        DateTime date2 = DateTime.Now; // текущая дата
        int ts = ((TimeSpan)(date2 - day1)).Days;
        /* Console.WriteLine(ts.Days);*/ // получаем разницу дней
        return ts;
    }

    public string GetdateByFormat(DateTime date, string format)
    {
        date = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        return format;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите месяц, день  год");
            int day = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int month = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int year = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            FunctionWithDate functionWithDate = new FunctionWithDate();
            DateTime enteredDate = new DateTime(day, month, year);

            int differentBeetweenDate = functionWithDate.DifferentInDays(enteredDate);
            Console.WriteLine(enteredDate);
            Console.WriteLine(differentBeetweenDate);

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            string getDateByFormat = functionWithDate.GetdateByFormat(enteredDate,"dd/mm/yyyy");
            Console.WriteLine(getDateByFormat);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. There are lots of examples on the [MSDN DateTIme ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_) web page

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. You can't assign a string to a DateTime struct. However, if you look at the MSDN link provided above you should be able to use the _format_ parameter to replace the argument for ToString() and get the date transformed in a string as you require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to modify your `GetDateByFormat()` method:

```
public string GetdateByFormat(DateTime date, string format)
{
    return date.ToString(format);
}
```

then, you can call this method like below:

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
string dateAsString = GetDateByFormat(currentDate, "dd/MM/yyyy");
Console.WriteLine(dateAsString);
```

which prints: `10/12/2019`

or like:

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
string dateAsString = GetDateByFormat(currentDate, "MM yy, dd");
Console.WriteLine(dateAsString);
```

which prints: `12 19, 10`

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ToString()` on `DateTime` objects to specify the format - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

You would need something like -

```
DateTime enteredDate = new DateTime(day, month, year);

Console.WriteLine(enteredDate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy"));
Console.WriteLine(enteredDate.ToString("dd MM yyyy"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ToString` method on `DateTime` object.

For example: `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")`

Answer (score 0):

this is an example that display date in many format

```
static void Main(string[] args)  
    {  
        // Get current DateTime. It can be any DateTime object in your code.  
        DateTime aDate = DateTime.Now;  

        // Format Datetime in different formats and display them  
        Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));  
        Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"));  
        Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"));  
        Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"));  
        Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"));  
        Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"));  
        Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"));  
        Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"));  
        Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"));  
        Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy H:mm"));  
        Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt"));  
        Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));  
        Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("MMMM dd"));  
        Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("yyyy’-‘MM’-‘dd’T’HH’:’mm’:’ss.fffffffK"));  
        Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyy HH’:’mm’:’ss ‘GMT’"));  
        Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("yyyy’-‘MM’-‘dd’T’HH’:’mm’:’ss"));  
        Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("HH:mm"));  
        Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("hh:mm tt"));  
        Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("H:mm"));  
        Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("h:mm tt"));  
        Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));  
        Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("yyyy MMMM"));  

        Console.ReadKey();  
    }
```